# Uniqueness of R-matrix

Tags: quantum-groups

This probably has an easy answer, but is there any sense in which the following statement is true:

> Let $U$ be a quantum enveloping algebra with universal $R$-matrix denoted by $R$, then $R$ is unique.

So I am wondering if (1) there is a suitable definition of this uniqueness and (2) where I can find a proof of this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R matrices are not unique.  See Chari's book for a classification of equivalence.

Comment: thanks! No wonder something like this isn't claimed in Turaev+Kassell.